# Password manager that does not require entry of master password when strarting browser

Tags: password-manager

I am looking for a password manager for a naive user.  This means he has a tendency to close his browser when he is done with it, instead of just minimizing it.  Teaching him not to do this is out of the question.  All the password managers I have seen require you to enter a master password (usually just once) upon starting the browser.  This behavior is unacceptable in my situation.  I want a password manager which is

1. secure and
2. requires manual entry of a master password not more than once after the user logs into his Windows account and
3. allows for syncing across multiple devices.

Comment: perhaps a dedicated password manager outside of the browser like [keepass](https://keepass.info/) could work for them

Answer (score 0):

Bitwarden has the option "never" under "vault timeout". To keep some security while reducing the hassle you could set up a PIN.

Answer (score 0):

At work chrome logs in when we login to the work station.

I don't know how this works, but the authentication of chrome is linked to that of the workstation. So I only login once. Even if I start chrome hours latter, or shut it down and re-start it.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will do the trick.  It has an option to set **Master Password**, now called **Primary Password**.  Simply untick the option.

[image]